# Restful insert problem - how to fix that?

Tags: java, android, rest

To pass the test, we need to use some webservice to get data from a database and send them to the app to use it. All of this works fine, but I'm stuck at sending data from android to the webservice. The webservice works fine on computer (I can put the url with the parameters in my firefox and it works fine and insert without problem), but if I try to call this url with the good parameters but launch it in my application, it doesn't do anything. No error (maybe I just don't see them, I'm not familiar with the android studio debugger).

```
private class WebServicePut extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{
    private final String url2 = "http://192.168.1.12:8080/PortPontrieuxWebService/webresources/emplacement/envoyer?nomBateau="+nomDuBateau+"&portBateau="+nomDuPort+"&dateArrivee="+DateDeDepart+"&dateDepart="+DateDeFin+"&reglement="+reglement+"&idEmpl="+idEmpl;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Début de requete insert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient c2 = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet req2 = new HttpGet(url2);
            req2.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            req2.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            HttpResponse response = c2.execute(req2);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String retourneWS = rd.readLine();
            return retourneWS;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Function call:

```
@GET
@Path("envoyer")
public void getJSON(@QueryParam("nomBateau") String pnomBateau,@QueryParam("portBateau") String pNomPort,@QueryParam("dateArrivee") String pdateArrivee,@QueryParam("dateDepart") String pdateDepart,@QueryParam("reglement") String pReglement,@QueryParam("idEmpl") String pIdEmpl)
{
    gestionPort.insertEtModif(pnomBateau, pNomPort, pdateArrivee, pdateDepart, pReglement, pIdEmpl);
}
```

And the "insertEtModif" function:

```
public static void insertEtModif(String nomBateau,String nomPort,String dateArrivee,String dateDepart,String reglement,String idEmplacement)
{
    try{
        CollectionEmplacements = new ArrayList<Emplacement>();
        Class.forName(pilote);                                  
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String req = "INSERT INTO `louer` (`nomBateau`, `portBateau`, `dateArrivee`, `dateDepart`, `reglement`, `emplacement_id`,`commentaire`) VALUES ('"+nomBateau+"', '"+nomPort+"', '"+dateArrivee+"', '"+dateDepart+"', '"+reglement+"', '"+idEmplacement+"','');";
        System.out.println(req);
        int retour2 = stmt.executeUpdate(req);
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String req2 = "UPDATE `emplacement` SET `disponible` = '1' WHERE `emplacement`.`id` = "+idEmplacement ;
        System.out.println(req2);
        int retour = stmt.executeUpdate(req2);
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I know we don't use GET but PUT usually, but it was to test if the URL was correct, and it works directly in a browser (tested with Firefox).

Comment: Why are you adding the header attributes addHeader("Accept", "application/json"); and addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); with JSON? Your request has nothing to do with JSON.  GET sends data by way of parameters not CONTENT. If you want to send content then do so with POST and structure your REST webserver accordingly.

Comment: @Barns to be honest, i reused some code they gave us yesterday, but now that i think about it, they are useless and im sorry for not noticing it before, these line were in a function that retrieved json data, but this has nothing to do in an insert one

Comment: No reason to apologize. I have used both GET and POST to send requests to webservices. When I am in control of the webservice then I prefer POST. I feel it gives me more control--I can send the data as I chose.

Comment: well, somebody found why, didnt put " URLEncorder.encode(url) " thank you anyway